# how to customize wordpress with android connectivity

Tags: android, web-services, wordpress

I am new to WordPress and I am going to build an application on Android, where all the data will be stored on WordPress database (like users and posts). What should I do to make my WordPress to registered users through android app and show other data too?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the open source project (WordPress for Android).The source is available here https://android.trac.wordpress.org/browser. You can customize this as per your requirements..

Comment: I want to create a CMS on wordpress to screening point of view which handle all the information of application on web. please guide me
Thanks

Comment: As per my experience we could manage it by posts.But need some work to made them as public/private etc. as per our requirements.If you have much number of data categories you could manage this with your own custom tables in addition of WP_POSTS and relate these with corresponding post_id.